# Google's text-to-speech (WaveNet) quality degrades with long texts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

Using the API with the Swedish voice `sv-SE-Wavenet-A`, it seems that the quality of the audio degrades with longer texts.

**Short text:**

> Det ter sig logiskt att man gått över till tvångsfinansiering av en
>   kanal som under året alltså tappade sex procent av tittartiden. Till
>   slut kommer ingen titta, men alla kommer ändå tvingas betala.

**Long text (bold = short text from above):**

> SVT backade sex procent - endast en tredjedel tittas - tvingas betala
>   ändå Preliminära siffror från mätföretaget MMS visar på att
>   vuxendagiset SVT tappade sex procent av sin tittartid under 2018. Nu
>   tittas det på endast en dryg tredjedel av tiden på SVT, men alla i
>   Sverige tvingas ändå betala sedan årsskiftet. SVT. SVT:s tittarsiffror
>   tappade till 34.9% i så kallad tittartidsandel. Det tvångsfinansierade
>   vuxendagiset har alltså bara en dryg tredjedel av tittartiden, men
>   samtliga med inkomst i Sverige måste likväl betala för detta.
>   Siffrorna från MMS är preliminära och SVT ska ha 34.9% av tittartiden,
>   TV4-gruppen 31.9%, Discovery Networks-gruppen 11.9%, och Nordic
>   Entertainment Group 11.6%. Discovery inkluderar Kanal 5 och Nordic
>   Entertaingment TV3. **Det ter sig logiskt att man gått över till**
>   **tvångsfinansiering av en kanal som under året alltså tappade sex**
>   **procent av tittartiden. Till slut kommer ingen titta, men alla kommer**
>   **ändå tvingas betala.** Socialism baserar sig på tvång när folk inte
>   frivilligt gör det som socialisterna vill åstakomma. Det är en ren
>   skam att de borgerliga partierna var med och drev igenom
>   tvångsfinansieringen av det konsekvenslösa vuxendagiset. Lämplig
>   åtgärd är att istället koda SVT, så får de som vill betala för detta
>   göra det och övriga slipper. Så kan också SVT falla bort i glömskan.
>   Tills detta sker kommer förstås bloggen bevaka SVT:s felsteg, men kom
>   ihåg att anmälningar till granskningsnämnden ej ska göras då det
>   legitimerar ett sjukt och helt konsekvenslöst meningslöst system. SVT
>   är ett aktiebolag, som besitter beskattningsrätt av svenska folket.
>   Nedanstående kommentarer är inte en del av det redaktionella
>   innehållet och användare ansvarar själva för sina kommentarer. Se även
>   kommentarsreglerna, inklusive listan med kommentatorer som automatiskt
>   kommer raderas på grund av brott mot dessa. Genom att kommentera
>   samtycker du till att din kommentar, tidsstämpel, profillänk och
>   pseudonym sparas av Googles Blogger-system så länge det är relevant,
>   dvs så länge blogginlägget är publicerat.

**API Request**

```
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech')
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient()
client.synthesizeSpeech({
  input: text,
  voice: {
    languageCode: 'sv-SE',
    ssmlGender: 'FEMALE',
    name: 'sv-SE-Wavenet-A',
  },
  audioConfig: {
    audioEncoding: 'MP3',
  },
})
```

**Results from the API**

- [Short text audio](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mflVbBm03YGgbBPnqP6CyXWyYdxN2cKn)
- [Long text audio](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TvhFndxcbqLH0YCh8LCHXKFYV4rESw1L)
- [Audio comparison](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11DHJTRvVmADwbUqWQLU8lht-oNF1Y1hC)

The audio comparison first plays the result I got when sending the short text. It then plays the same text, but cut out from the result I got when sending the long text. Finally, it plays them both together.

Is this a bug or expected? I haven't noticed any degradation of quality at all when using the en-US or en-GB voices.

<s>I noticed that the Swedish voice uses a different naturalSampleRateHertz than all the other voices, perhaps that might cause this?</s>

Comment: I had the same issue and contact the guys at voicesurfer.com. They told me, that they have split the wavents into several parts and then concat them. Feel free to contact them as well. Do you have tried to split and stich your text?

Comment: @GaryHilgemann I split text into chunks and concat the result to overcome the 5k-character per request limit. Chunks are about 3-4.5k in length. Any shorter and I would quickly hit the request per minute limit... so this is really not an option I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably more related to using [MP3 as encoding format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Encoding_and_decoding) than to any sample rate difference with other languages. Since MP3 is a lossy format, it is expected that some quality might be lost; the differences between the short file and the longer file are probably related to [MP3 encoding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#Quality) being used.

I have checked in my side the [Speech Synthesis API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/texttospeech/texttospeech/v1/texttospeech.voices.list), and the "sv-SE-Wavenet-A" voice seems to be using a naturalSampleRateHertz of 24000, as all the wavenet I have checked (all en-US-Wavenet voices are in 24000 as well).

I would recommend to you to [change the audioEncoding flag](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize#AudioEncoding) to some other encoding format, for example "OGG_OPUS", which will yield a better audio quality.

```
  audioConfig: {
    audioEncoding: 'OGG_OPUS',
  },
```

If the MP3 format is a must, you can then change the format in your side, so you can choose which parameters you deem convenient in your MP3 encoding to ensure the maximum audio quality, whilst the audio file is compressed.

Comment: You're right about the sample rate, I accidentally looked at the sv-SE-Standard-A voice when writing this post  However, I'm pretty sure this is not related to encoding issues. Then I would notice the same quality degradation using the EN voices as well. Besides, there are subtle, but noticeable, differences in pronunciation and speed between the short and long version (I'm a native swede, so this might be more obvious to me)

Comment: It could be possible that the text-to-speech algorithm treats differently the two texts, maybe depending on the context. I would still recommend to change the API call parameters, to use an encoding format with better audio quality and bitrate ('OGG_OPUS'), and check if the issue persists.

Comment: We have tested lossless LINEAR16 as well, and the issue still remains. It sounds very bad to be honest. Almost like the speaker doesn't pause to breathe after each sentence and becomes more and more stressed as she reads. Who should I contact with this issue?

Comment: @Mickel try wrapping every sentence between `<s>` `</s>`. That fixed the problem for me where the voice seems to not correctly pause.

Comment: Stop, full stop (followed by new line) and end of paragraph have different pause duration, whether it is read by a human or a Neural Network. (garbage in, garbage out).